# How to recursively change color of element

Tags: javascript, html, recursion

I want to create a program that recursively changes the color of text.

I've already created a `for(){}`  loop with the random color code in it in order to attempt to recurse it.

```
 for(var x = 0; x > -1; x++){
 document.getElementById("k").style.color = '#'+(0x1000000+ 
 (Math.random())*0xffffff).toString(16).substr(1,6)}

 <p id="k">Yeet</p>
```

The actual result is that the color stays at it's default, black. I would like it to be that every time it runs (infinitely), it will change colors.

Comment: It's staying black because you cause an infinite loop before the browser is ever able to render a new color. You also change the new color so quickly that you'd never see it anyways.

Comment: Using that for loop is causing an "infinite loop", and you are going to see nothing at all. Use a setInterval function instead.

Comment: Why do you want/need to use recursion?

Comment: Would you accept a CSS solution instead of javascript? An example of this can be seen if you hover any link (including the photo) on this page: https://meowni.ca/posts/polymer-2-cheatsheet/

Answer (score 6):

You have to use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) method to run asynchronously without blocking the main execution.

```js
setInterval(() => document.getElementById("k").style.color = '#' + (0x1000000 +(Math.random()) * 0xffffff).toString(16).substr(1, 6),500)
```

```html
<p id="k">Yeet</p>
```

---

If you want to stop at some point then use [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) method to clear the interval.

```js
let i = 0;

const inter = setInterval(() => {
  document.getElementById("k").style.color = '#' + (0x1000000 + (Math.random()) * 0xffffff).toString(16).substr(1, 6);
  // to clear after 10 colors
  if (i++ === 10) clearInterval(inter);
}, 500)
```

```html
<p id="k">Yeet</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/** Bad recursive pattern.
 * 
 * All recursive methods should have a base case,
 * I assume you want the change to stop at some point,
 * if not you have an infinite loop running.
 * 
 * This function can still time out if it takes too long to hit "theLastColor"
 */
function recursiveColorChange(id, currentColor) {
    const theLastColor = '#some-value';
    if (currentColor === theLastColor) {
        return;
    }
    const randomColor = '#' + (0x1000000 + (Math.random()) * 0xffffff).toString(16).substr(1, 6);
    document.getElementById(id).style.color = randomColor;
    return recursiveRandomColor(id, randomColor);
}
```

However, using the pure recursive code prevents controlling color change Z_BEST_SPEED.
As mentioned by @pranav-c-balan, I think it is better to use setTimeout.
You can still have a base case where you stop changing colors by using clearTimeout();

```
/** Better setTimeOut pattern.
 * 
 * You can pass a lastColor value if you want it to stop if it reaches a color.
 * Or you can just pass it an id and a speed (in milliseconds) and it will run forever without breaking your code.
 */
function repeatColorChange(id, speed, lastColor) {
    const myTimeOut = setTimeout(() => {
        const randomColor = '#' + (0x1000000 + (Math.random()) * 0xffffff).toString(16).substr(1, 6);
        document.getElementById(id).style.color = randomColor;

        if (randomColor === lastColor) {
            clearTimeout(myTimeOut);
        }
    }, speed);
}
```